Detecting which process/program is running and consuming energy while Mac is sleep
I am recently having an issue with my MacBook M1 Max which uses a relatively high energy while in sleep mode. I disabled power nap (Wake for network access), yet it uses almost high CPU time and network bandwidth.
How can I detect which process or app is causing this issue?
Here are a few graphs: my MacBook was sleeping from 3 pm last day until 6 am today, but the battery drops more than 20 percent.
Note that I usually have docker desktop running and almost 6-7 containers are loaded and running on it like postgres and tomcat which can be the source of issue but I can't verify it.
Battery history from Mac:

CPU usage during sleep time

Network usage during sleep time

battery level from iStat menu

My nap configurations

here is the output of pmset -g log during sleep time in one of durations that it looks like the mac wakes:
2024-05-01 05:55:32 +0330 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [AirPort configd plug-in is slow(340 ms)] [com.apple.bluetooth.sleep is slow(1575 ms)]
2024-05-01 06:04:22 +0330 Assertions            PID 410(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009422 [System: PrevIdle]
2024-05-01 06:04:22 +0330 Assertions            PID 420(nsurlsessiond) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "NSURLSessionTask 1E5095F9-9F28-40DD-8D60-E8CE2804F25C" 00:08:59  id:0x0x1000093ef [System: PrevIdle]
2024-05-01 06:04:22 +0330 Assertions            PID 312(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000942c [System: PrevIdle]
2024-05-01 06:04:22 +0330 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to NUB.SPMISw3IRQ nub-spmi0.0x02 rtc/Maintenance Using BATT (Charge:97%) 6 secs
2024-05-01 06:04:22 +0330 WakeDetails           DriverReason:NUB.SPMISw3IRQ - DriverDetails:
DriverReason:nub-spmi0.0x02 - DriverDetails:
DriverReason:rtc - DriverDetails:
2024-05-01 06:04:22 +0330 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        rd=470 ms
2024-05-01 06:04:22 +0330 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.132 sec
2024-05-01 06:04:22 +0330 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(114 ms)]
2024-05-01 06:04:22 +0330 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 1)(78 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(141 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(107 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(77 ms)] [AppleAVD driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(103 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(143 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(112 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(76 ms)] [AppleAVD driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(105 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(131 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(140 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(106 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(78 ms)] [AppleAVD driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(105 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(139 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(111 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(75 ms)] [AppleAVD driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(105 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(131 ms)] [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(140 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(137 ms)] [AppleCS42L84Audio driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(77 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 1)(77 ms)] [AppleAVD driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(104 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(134 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(104 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(74 ms)] [AppleAVD driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(104 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(142 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(113 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 1)(77 ms)] [AppleCS42L84Audio driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(77 ms)] [AppleAVD driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(104 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(127 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(129 ms)] [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(141 ms)] [AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(110 ms)]
2024-05-01 06:04:22 +0330 Assertions            PID 410(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009422 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep IPushSrvc kCPU]
2024-05-01 06:04:25 +0330 Assertions            PID 420(nsurlsessiond) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "NSURLSessionTask C76C3CD3-9559-4245-A6AB-218B207B3C3F" 00:08:59  id:0x0x100009417 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2024-05-01 06:04:26 +0330 Assertions            PID 420(nsurlsessiond) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "NSURLSessionTask 1DF22E71-ADDE-4D0C-AA76-4A985ADAB8F4" 00:09:02  id:0x0x1000093fb [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2024-05-01 06:04:26 +0330 Assertions            PID 420(nsurlsessiond) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "NSURLSessionTask CC0C6AD5-AAAB-48B4-A737-2D838BF76DCD" 00:09:03  id:0x0x1000093f1 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2024-05-01 06:04:26 +0330 Assertions            PID 420(nsurlsessiond) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "NSURLSessionTask 2CEF9884-13BC-4265-ABB9-44204DB14CDC" 00:09:02  id:0x0x1000093fa [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2024-05-01 06:04:26 +0330 Assertions            PID 420(nsurlsessiond) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "NSURLSessionTask 259EAA91-9243-4F3E-B0FE-001C736DC3EA" 00:09:03  id:0x0x1000093f3 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2024-05-01 06:04:28 +0330 Assertions            PID 312(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:05  id:0x0xd0000942c [System: PrevIdle]
2024-05-01 06:04:28 +0330 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:97%) 535 secs
2024-05-01 06:04:29 +0330 Wake Requests         [*process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=533 wakeAt=2024-05-01 06:13:23 info="DHCP lease renewal"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=264382 wakeAt=2024-05-04 07:30:51] [process=powerd request=CSPNEvaluation deltaSecs=3112 wakeAt=2024-05-01 06:56:21] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=1893 wakeAt=2024-05-01 06:36:03 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-com.apple.calaccessd.travelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer,75504"]


Are you able to confirm your Mac was really sleeping and not just dimming the display? pmset -g log can be useful for this. Does the output of pmset -g assertions show any processes blocking system sleep?

@GrahamMiln thanks for your feedback. I added the related output of pmset -g log to my question body. it indicates there is some activity yet I can't detect any cause for that

The energy tab in Activity Monitor shows the apps which use most energy. Is there any specific one on top?
